# FileUpload from Subdomain to Folder of Main Domain

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, visual-studio-2013, code-behind

I tried ridiculous searches and don't really know what to search.

I'm less than a novice in programming (graphic designer that knows too much), is it possible to have a subdomain website upload files to the parent website.

The current code is:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
  {
    string webPath = "~/Uploads/Files/";
```

I have tried:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
  {
    string webPath = "http://domain.com/Uploads/Files/";
```

Any help and direction would be appreciated, thanks!

**Update 01**

I've also tried:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
  {
    string webPath = "../../httpdocs/Uploads/Files/";
```

which gave the following error: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

**Update 02**

After some more googling I suspected that I'm calling some path twice. So I got this to work, but I'm not entirely sure how secure it is.

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
  {
    string sysPath = "C:/Inetpub/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/Uploads/Files/";
```

Then for downloading again, there's a separate file *Download.aspx* where I had to change the code as follows

```
response.TransmitFile("C:/Inetpub/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/Uploads/Files/" + filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's normally .. to go up a level so ../ would go up one level, easy way to get the path is to drag something from a folder into the ide in source code mode and it will create a link with the correct path and ditch the HTTP, your not loading a resource like you would an image, your just saying use this folder path

Comment: No luck... Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

Comment: can you download an image from the parent ? then change the updload path to the img src minus the name off course, from here have no clue what you server upload path would be without more info like a src URL ! also when u do ~/ your using relative paths try this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relative-path

Comment: I do know what ~/ does, which is why I excluded it when trying out the different methods.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MikeH I came to a solution. In short for uploading...

```
// USE TO SAVE TO SERVER C:
string sysPath = "C:/Uploads/ClientFiles/";
```

and for downloading...

```
// USE TO DOWNLOAD FROM SERVER C:
Response.TransmitFile(@"C:/Uploads/ClientFiles/" + filename);
```

Don't forget to set the folder permissions as well. Please see the solution on my security question [How Secure is string sysPath = "C:/Inetpub/vhosts/..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22545331/2818528)

Comment: @MikeH this is also great because I don't have to change code between my local copy and the live copy :D

Answer (score 0):

I have done it this way:

```
string ThisDir = "E:/AjkerDealLatest/images/Deals";
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(ThisDir + "\\" + FolderNameHiddenField.Value);
ImageName = Request.Form.GetValues("name");
string path = Path.Combine("E:/AjkerDealLatest/images/Deals/"+ FolderNameHiddenField.Value, ImageName[0] + ".jpg");

file.SaveAs(path);
```