# How Secure is string sysPath = "C:/Inetpub/vhosts/..."

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, visual-studio-2013, code-behind

I have a little more detailed question, [FileUpload from Subdomain to Folder of Main Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22536660/2818528), which I kinda solved, but I'm just not sure how secure my solution is.

In short, a logged in person can upload files, but they're on subdomain and the files are getting stored in the parent domain's folders. So I'm using:

```
string sysPath = "C:/Inetpub/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/Uploads/Files/"
```

Is the acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking if these files are safe from unauthorized access.  The answer is "Not really".  Those files are accessible by anyone able to guess (or otherwise obtain) the path to the files.  I'd recommend storing them outside of the Inetpub folder (Something like `C:\Uploads\`).  Once you've authenticated your user (i.e. the user is logged in somehow) you can stream/send the file like this:

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
    Response.TransmitFile(fullFilePath);
    Response.End();
```

`filename` is just the file name, not the full path.

**EDIT**: A little bit more detail

When you upload the file (as described in your other post) just be sure to store the file in a directory that doesn't include `Inetpub`.  So, say your user uploads a file called `foo.gif`.  You'll want to store it at `C:\Uploads\foo.gif` (in your `upload.aspx`).  Now when someone visits `Download.aspx` run the following code:

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="foo.gif");
    Response.TransmitFile(@"C:\uploads\foo.gif");
    Response.End();
```

I've shown the values hard coded for clarity.

Comment: Hi @MikeH , this is a little over my head, could you maybe have a look at the question "http://stackoverflow.com/q/22536660/2818528" that got us here, unless you have and this answers both sort of...

Comment: Shot @MikeH, uploading now to see if it works on the live server.

Comment: Works like a charm, of course I had to go set some permissions, but I'm happy! Thanks